# How to inject current user in the Hibernate rev Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-envers

I used Spring 3.1, JPA 2 and Spring Data JPA(Hibenrate 4.1) in my project, and used Hibernate Envers(shipped with Hibernate 4) to audit some properties, I want to store the current logged in user in the related rev table, how to implement this? Thanks.

Comment: In the old days, I used to have a thread-local storage for the current login session. If you have similar things in your app, the answer should be obvious right?

Answer (score 3):

you will need to create Custom Envers listner as below

```
public class CustomEnversListener implements RevisionListener {
@Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
       CustomRevisionEntity customRevisionEntity = (customRevisionEntity)revisionEntity;
       Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       customRevisionEntity.setUsername(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

for more information please look at hibernate [wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MyExperienceWithHibernateEnvers-AuditTrail)